# Accessing Items in an Array - AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've got an Object `item.movieimage` that contain some texts (`item:Object`) that is retrieve from my database. The text is changing every week automatically.

If I do `trace(item.movieimage)` the `output` is something like this :

```
text1 
text2
text3 
text4
```

The words changes as the code is taking them from my database. The database changes the words every week.

Now, I want my AS3 code to display the third element of `item.movieimage`.

I've tried to do this :

```
var my_str:String = item.movieimage+",";
var ary:Array = my_str.split(",");
    trace(ary[2]);
```

But it's not working. The output is "`undefined`".

Do you know how can I access a specific item in the Array that I've created ? Or how can I access the third item of `item.movieimage` ?

If I do  `trace(ary);`, the output is :

```
text1, 
text2,
text3,
text4,
```

EDIT :

For infos :
`trace(typeof(item.movieimage))` and `trace(typeof(ary))` are :

```
typeof(item.movieimage)=string
typeof(ary)=object
```

EDIT 2 :

Here's a screen capture of item.movieimage

[Screen Cap of item.movieimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrHlm.png)

**EDIT 3**

Here's my code in order to understand how "item.movieimage"is working

```
 //Variables for downloading content from my database to my AS3 code

var urlReqSearchAll: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.myWebSite/searchMovie4.php");
    var loader5:URLLoader = new URLLoader();


//downloading content 

        function searchAll():void { 
            if (contains(list)){
                list.removeChildren();  
            }
            urlReqSearchAll.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
                loader5.load(urlReqSearchAll);
                loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,complete);

            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();    
}

//Content Downloaded. 

        function complete(e:Event):void {

    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
hourSaved.data.saved=loader5.data;
     products.reverse();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
}
    displayPage(0);
    showList();
}


// If too much items --> creates multiple page

const itemsPerPage:uint = 7;
var currentPageIndex:int = 0;

function displayPage(pageIndex:int):void {
    list.removeChildren();
    currentPageIndex = pageIndex;
    var firstItemIndex:int = pageIndex * itemsPerPage;
    var j:int = 0;
    var lastItemIndex: int = firstItemIndex + 7; // as lastItemIndex should be 10 more
 if (lastItemIndex > products.length) // if lastindex is greater than products length
 lastItemIndex = products.length;
 for(var i:int = firstItemIndex; i< lastItemIndex; i++){
 createListItem( j, products[i]); // j control the position and i points to particular element of array..
 j++;
 }
    next.visible = lastItemIndex < products.length - 1;
        if(currentPageIndex==0){
        previous.visible=false;
    }
}


// Display the information downloded from my database

function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {

var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = item.title.length > 13 ? 22 : 26
    listItem.multiline = true;
    listItem.wordWrap = true;
    myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
    myFormat.color = 0xA2947C;
    myFormat.font = "Ebrima";
    myFormat.bold = true;
    listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;  
    listItem.x = 135;
    listItem.y = 123+ index * 84;
    listItem.width = 200;
    listItem.height = 80;
 listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);
    str = item.title;


}
```

My php file "SearchMovie4.php" is like this :

```
$products = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    $products[] = array(
"title" => $row["theTitle"],
"movieimage" => $row["movieimage"],
"movielength" => $row["movielength"],
"story" => $row["story"],
    );
} 
echo json_encode($products);
```

So, if I do `trace(item.movieimage)` in AS3 code, it will display all the items in the row movieimage of my database.

If I do  `trace(item.title)` in AS3 code, it will display all the items in the row title of my database.

What I'd like is to be able to do, in my AS3 code, `trace(item.movieimage[2])` in order to show me the third item in the row "movieimage".

Comment: You may have forgotten to enclose the value for the property inside quotation marks! Change it to: `"one, three, sixteen, fourteen";`, or you may have intended otherwise, in which case, please clarify :)

Comment: You're right, my original post wasn't clear. I've edited my post and hope I clarified it.

Comment: Show traces for typeof(item.movieimage), typeof(ary), ary.length

Comment: `typeof(item.movieimage)=string` 
`typeof(ary)=object`

Comment: **Re: Edit 3** Ok, I think you're confused about the output you're seeing. The code you posted doesn't `trace()` anything, or `split()` anything (you say you tried that but you don't show or say *where*, which matters), but my guess is that you did `trace(item.movieimage)` within `createListItem()` which would output every `item.movieimage` value, but this *does not mean you have a single string separated by newlines* like we all thought. If you did `trace(index, item.movieimage)` you can confirm this. What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: I've tried to add `var movies:Array = item.movieimage.split("\n");` and then `trace(movies[2])` within `createListItem()`. I did `trace(index, item.movieimage)` and the output was `0 http://www.cinecity.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/xxx_3.jpg
1 http://www.cinecity.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/vaiana.jpg
2 http://www.cinecity.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/tous_scene.jpg
//etc..` What I'm trying to do (**my purpose**) is to do, for example, `secondMovie = item.movieimage[1]` (so, in this example, `secondMovie` would be `=` to `http://www.cinecity.nc/Content/images/AFFICHES/vaiana.jpg`

Comment: Do you see what I'm saying? You were not tracing a single multiline string like you made it sound like... you were tracing multiple strings from a loop. `item.movieimage` is **a single string**. To get the second movie just use `secondMovie = products[1].movieimage`.

Comment: OOoooh Ok, I understand what I was doing !! Thank you mate ! All clear now

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *text* you've provided to the `movieimage` property of the `item` object has not the same *[delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)* as what you have provided to the [`split()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()) method; in your case the character of comma!

---

I suspect the delimiter you have, is the *"space"* character or a [new-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character, like the character of *[carriage retrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)*.
In the following code snippet, I've used the *"space"* as the delimiter character:

```
var item:Object = new Object();
item.movieimage = "text1 text2 text3 text4";
var my_str:String = item.movieimage;
var ary:Array = my_str.split(" ");
trace(ary[2]); // text3
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but, no, `item.movieimage` can't be `=` to `"text1 text2 text3 text4"`; I type `"text1, text2 text3 text4"` as an example. `item.movieimage = some texts`. It retrieves infos from my database

Comment: It's a `String` at the end of the database retrieving process! You just need to figure the delimiter character, that's all!

Comment: I've tried to added a delimiter with `var my_str:String = item.movieimage+",";` as I don't know what is the delimiter. I've edited my orginal post with a screen capture. Maybe you will see what is the delimiter...? (for information, i've tried also with "/n" but no success..)

Comment: A delimiter is basically used to separate fields; As I've stated in the answer, it _may_ be a new line character (so it's not _necessarily_ a _visible_ character), you specify the delimiter as the argument for the `split()` method; From your screenshot, it's most probably a newline character, like CR, or LF, or both altogether! So, try `"\n"` or `"\r"` or `"\n\r"` as the input for the `split()` method, e.g: `var ary:Array = my_str.split("\n");` :)

Answer (score 0):

As @someOne said the output shows the list items are each on a new line, so you need to `split()` against newlines. One of these should work:

```
// if server uses "\n" newline char
var movies:Array = item.movieimage.split("\n");

// if server uses "\r" carriage return char
var movies:Array = item.movieimage.split("\r");

// if you aren't sure or there's a mixture of newline chars
var movies:Array = item.movieimage.split(/[\r|\n]+/);
```

Also note that if you have any control over how the server returns these values, you should just return a JSON array (since I see in your screenshot you are already decoding JSON), then you won't have to do any string splitting.

Comment: thx you for your answer. Could you explain to me how could I return a JSON array please ? Indeed, I'm decoding a JSON in this line :  `products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;`

Comment: I've tried each lines you told me. Doesn't throw error but still return "undefined" when I do `trace(movies[2]);` (in order to have the third item in the array).

Comment: I've tried :  `var myArray:Array ;
 var myObject:Object;
 myObject = item.movieimage;
 myArray.push(myObject);` but error : Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Comment: You need to show all your code related to this (loading, parsing, tracing), either `item.movieimage` is not what you said in your original post, or the way you are using `movies` is not correct.